# Receiving 403 Forbidden error when running Cypress test, but receiving no error when manually navigating to the app

Tags: cypress

Below is a step in my Cypress test:

```
Given('I visit the webiste', () => {
    cy.visit('https://dealerportal-test.santanderconsumerusa.com/dealer/login/')
})
```

**Actual Cypress Behaviour:**

- I get a 403 error below:

> cy.visit() failed trying to load:
> https://dealerportal-test.santanderconsumerusa.com/dealer/login/
> The response we received from your web server was:
>
> > 403: Forbidden
>
> This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx.
>
> If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option:
> failOnStatusCode: false

[image: network requetss & UI error when running the automation]

**Actual Manual Behaviour:**

- I'm able to manually navigate to the website without a problem, & here are the network requests being made:

[image: network requests when manually going to website]

Is there a better way to handle this issue rather than just setting `failOnStatusCode: false`?

I'm not sure why the manual behaviour is different to the automated behaviour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your cypress.json config file write this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://dealerportal-test.santanderconsumerusa.com",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Then in yor test try this:

```
   cy.visit('/', {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'user-agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
        }
    });
```

Comment: I encounter 403 in google auth, this not solving.

Comment: I couldn't access bet365 with this hack - probably they use some special protection... Maybe there is a workaround by faking a regular user's fingerprint (data like screen resolution etc), but I have no idea how to do that :D

Comment: @Pongbao I'm currently active in Playwright instead of Cypress. Because of a lot of problem that's blocking me when using Cypress.

I don't know how to solve it yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    cy.visit(url, {
    failOnStatusCode: false,
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue only hides it